# How to use checkbox to complete tasks in a to do list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I am a newbie in React and I've been working on a simple To-do list with State Hooks. I am having trouble to assign `style={{textDecoration: Checkbox.checked ? "line-through" : "" }}` with the function

```
function Checkbox(){
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    return (
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
      </label>
    );
  }
```

in order to complete some tasks. The task should be default "Task" but once checked, I want the task to be crossed out: "T̶a̶s̶k̶". I will post for you my attempt:

```html
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function TodoList({ todo, index, completeTodo, removeTodo}) {
    return (
      <div className="todo"> 
        <Checkbox />    
            <div style={{textDecoration: Checkbox.checked ? "" : "line-through" }} >
                {todo.text}
            </div>
        <div>
          <button class = "button" onClick={() => removeTodo(index)}>Delete Task</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Checkbox() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
    return (
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
      </label>
    );
  }

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: Strange that TodoList only renders a single Todo and you are deleting items from a list but use [index as key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html), look for `We don’t recommend using indexes for keys`. You also have `completeTodo` that comes from somewhere but you didn't think it be relevant to mention where it comes from in a question that's about how to complete a todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React works in a one-way data binding, this means that Child can see the parent state, but parents **can not** see child's state.

So in order to achieve what you are trying to do you can take two path.

1. (Easiest) Move the text inside the checkbox functional component, and doing that you can tie both elements (checkbox and text) and share the state.
2. (Hardest and not recommended in this case) Create a global state (using context api or Redux or whatever you want to use) to save the state of the checkbox in the global state and then read it within the TodoList component.

If you want to implement the first path you can do:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function TodoList({ todoList }) {
    const onRemoveItem = () => {
      //remove item from todoList
    }

    return (
      <div className="todo"> 
        <Checkbox onRemoveItem={onRemoveItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Checkbox({ onRemoveItem }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
    return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
      </label>
      <div style={{textDecoration: checked ? "" : "line-through" }} >
        {todo.text}
      </div>
      <button class = "button" onClick={() => onRemoveItem()}>Delete Task</button>
    </>
    );
  }

export default TodoList;
```